# How to set dynamic value to "value" attribute of struts html:button tag?

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts

I am using following button tag to display button by passing some runtime value to "value" attribute:

```
<html:button  styleClass="button50" value="<%=no_list %>" onclick="callOneFunction(this);" />
```

it is throwing an jasper exception saying, setValue(String) cannot work with html:button.

Please help me out to resolve my problem, I want to pass some value at runtime to value attribute. How to do it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you have to write.

```
<html:submit styleClass="button50">
<%=no_list %>
</html:submit>
```